# Aligning nav bar to header image

Tags: css, html

Hopefully just a quick question: I am trying to make my nav bar appear next to my logo, however it is not working. I have tried the solutions provided on other questions and none seem to work. I have tried float:left; for my header and float:right; for the nav, but it does not display correctly. Thank you in advance for your help. Here is my code:

```css
body{
    width:90%;
    padding-left:3%;
    padding-right:3%;

}

header{
    float:left;
}

nav{
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    padding-left: 2em;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
header.banner > nav a:link{
     font-size:large;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    margin-right:20%;   
}
header.banner > nav a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

section{
    float:left;
    column-count:3;
    column-gap:2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<header class="banner">
<a title="Cleveland State University" href="http://www.csuohio.edu/">
<img src="CSU Shield.png" alt="CSUshield"
alt="navigation to Cleveland State University's website" />
</a>
<nav>
    <a href="cis.csuohio.edu/~hubteibe/CBA.html">Home</a>
    <a href="cis.csuohio.edu/~hubteibe/Internships.html">Internships</a>
    <a href="cis.csuohio.edu/~hubteibe/Co-Ops.html">Co-Ops</a>
    <a href="cis.csuohio.edu/~hubteibe/Careers.html">Careers</a>
</nav>
<h1>College of Business Internships, Co-Ops, and Career Programs</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: I think this is all you want to have - http://jsfiddle.net/d60zquo0/

Comment: when I put your css in, it took away the nav bar except for the links

Comment: There are some HTML changes too, make sure to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make following changes to your CSS,

```
header{
    float:left;
    width:100%
}
header > a{
    float: left;
}
nav{
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    padding-left: 2em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: left;
}
header.banner > nav a:link{
    font-size:large;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    padding: 0 20px;   
}
```

The property `margin-right: 20%` given to the `header.banner > nav a:link` was creating the problem. Usually, for these kind of situations you are supposed to use the left and right paddings.

<-------------UPDATE------------>

To take up the whole width, do something like this,

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
header > a{
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}
nav{
   white-space: nowrap;
   float: left;
   width: 80%;
   margin-bottom: 25px;
}
header.banner > nav a:link{
    font-size: large;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 20px;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;   
}
```

Comment: That worked well, thank you.  One thing though, the nav bar is now at the top to the left of the image, however the nav bar doesn't span the whole top of the page as you can see here: http://cis.csuohio.edu/~hubteibe/CBA.html. any ideas?

Comment: Your revisions lead me to the way I wanted it so thank you very much. I had to make the header 100% and the nav 80% and that did the trick. Another question: how do I have the links centered in the nav bar? they are clustered to the left right now.

Comment: I tried it, it did not work. the webpage has it now with some of the revisions you suggested.

Comment: add "width:25%" to the "header.banner > nav a:link" and add  "*{box-sizing: border-box;}" to your CSS

Comment: CSS `calc()` will help in this case, the logo is `width:170px`, then the nav would be `width: calc(100% - 170px);`, feel free to update the answer if you like it - http://jsfiddle.net/5trgf5y7/

Comment: Awesome! I added the width statement like you said, and it worked out! When I added box-sizing statement, it made the nav bar disappear besides the links, but just with the width:20% statement it is now exactly how I want it. Thank you! You are a lifesaver!